# Aapt does not run on arm architecture

Tags: linux, arm, aapt, apktool, aapt2

I'm using Nethunter, and the architecture is Linux arm, and I would love to use the apktool tool, I'm studying and reading pentest books, but I can't practice if I don't apply what's there, the problem is that for me  rebuild an apk using `apktool b app` it returns an error code 131, which according to the creator of apktool, is that aapt is not working for arm architecture, is there any way I can install aapt for arm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, as it is not possible to use this tool on Android devices, the solution I found was to use the **Apk Editor Pro** and change the files I need to change, but I found this **Haxus** tool that works on Android devices and does the same  work that apktool

> Haxus tool:
> https://github.com/Hax4us/Apkmod